# How to get real result from AxisEngine

Tags: apache-axis, apache-synapse, wso2-esb

I'm trying to implement my specific transport for WSO2 ESB based on some proprietary binary protocol. From protocol specification I need acknowledge every packet I receive only if I'm 100% sure that it will be processed in future. For those reasons some persistent store must be used.

I want to implement that protocol logic via WSO2 ESB sequence that gets protocol packets/messages and stores them to temporary `messageStore` which is used as a queue in producer/consumer pattern (where producer is transport itself and consumer is my packet processor).

I have to be sure that my packet got to the `messageStore` before sending acknowledge to the client. But `AxisEngine.receive()` does always return CONTINUE even if message store is not available.

The configuration of the proxy is:

```
<proxy name="MyProxyService">
    <target>
        <inSequence>
            <store messageStore="MyStore" sequence="onStoreSequence"/>
        </inSequence>
        <outSequence>
            <send/>
        </outSequence>
        <faultSequence>
            <makefault version="soap11" response="true">
                <code xmlns:tns="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope" value="tns:Receiver"/>
                <reason expression="get-property('ERROR_MESSAGE')"/>
            </makefault>
            <send/>
        </faultSequence>
    </target>
</proxy>
```

The code I use in transport is:

```
MessageContext msgContext = confContext.createMessageContext();
AxisConfiguration axisConf = confContext.getAxisConfiguration();
try {
   msgContext.setTransportIn(axisConf.getTransportIn(transportName));
   msgContext.setTransportOut(axisConf.getTransportOut(transportName));
   msgContext.setIncomingTransportName(Constants.TRANSPORT_LOCAL);
   msgContext.setAxisService(axisConf.getService("MyProxyService"));
   msgContext.setEnvelope(TransportUtils.createSOAPMessage(msgContext));
   msgContext.setServerSide(true);
   Handler.InvocationResponse response = AxisEngine.receive(msgContext);
   log.error(String.valueOf(response));
} catch (Exception e) {
   log.error("ERROR", e);
}
```

The behaviour I want to have is what I see in HTTP transport: http request from the client (SOAP UI) is translated to Axis2 MessageContext and delivered to MyProxyService. If everything is ok - I get positive response, otherwise - error code and SOAP fault.

Answer (score 0):

After additional investigation I can say that idea behind HTTP transport request/response is that for sending response the `HttpSender` not `HttpReceiver` is used. `HttpReceiver` gets request from HTTP connection, sets link to HTTP connection to the message context, uses `AxisEngine.receive()` to deliver message to the ESB and returns.

HTTP response itself is received via `HttpSender`, identified as response to the previous request (via empty *To* header) and sent to the connection referenced from the message context.